# Can't access value outside of completion handler

Tags: swift, closures

The following code gives me an error as 'return self.myID' should be at the last curly bracket. Although if I do that, it will claim self.myID as an unresolved identifier since it is outside of the closure. How can I make it so that I can access self.myID outside of the completion handler and place the return value.

```html
   func chatPartnerId() -> String? {
        nextrequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection! , result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            self.myID = result["id"] as! String
            return self.myID

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a `String` use a `completion handler`:

```
func chatPartnerId(completion: (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?)->()) {
        nextrequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection! , result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil){
               completion(result:nil,error:error)
            }
            else{
                self.myID = result["id"] as! String
                completion(result:self.myID, error:nil)
            }


        }
    }
```

Call it as

```
 chatPartnerId() { (result,error) -> Void in
       if let error = error{
          print(error)
       }
       if result != nil {
           print(result)

       }
    }
```